# Generate random float between two floats on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, swift

This works fine on iPhone 5 but not on iPhone 5S oder iPad Air.

**Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments**

Why?

```
func randomFloat(from:Float, to:Float) -> Float { 
    let rand:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 1000) / 1000
    return (rand) * (to - from) + from
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use CGFloat instead of Float

```
func randomFloat(from:CGFloat, to:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let rand:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 1000) / 1000
    return (rand) * (to - from) + from
}
```

The problem you're seeing is that CGFloat is aliased to different types depending on the architecture. For 32-bit ARM, (iPhone 4S and 5), it's a Float internally, but for arm64, it's actually a Double. If you just use CGFloat instead of Float for your type casts it will work fine